# What are the undefined constants and functions in Stern's 2011 paper?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, likelihood, ranking, bradley-terry-model

I'm reading the 2011 paper on ranking called [Moderated Paired Comparisons](https://doi.org/10.1111/j.1467-9876.2010.00751.x) by Steven E. Stern and there are no definitions given for some of the constants and functions in equation 1.

[image: Equation 1]

As you can see, for the definition of $X_{ijk}$ as the $k^{\text{th}}$ observed moderated paired comparison between objects $i$ and $j$, $k$ is never defined since we don't know what a moderated paired comparison is still.

Another issue is the definition of $\Gamma$ and $\phi$. It is not even clear whether they are functions or constants.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: This is not a rule, but it looks like $F(\cdot)$ then it's likely to be a function.

Comment: Also, the text reads:  "φ is a dispersion parameter"

Comment: The first line is the logarithm of the reciprocal of a [Beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Properties).

Comment: It's also interesting that they chose to use a hierarchy of parentheses $( \rightarrow \{ \rightarrow [$, but because they ommit a symbol for multiplication, it becomes unclear (without context) what's a product and what's a function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\Gamma$ is [Gamma-function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function), since he models outcomes as coming from [Beta distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution) this is how log-likelihood looks like. $\phi$ is a (dispersion) parameter (i.e. constant). Hope this helps.